# MySql executing a MySqlScript even when the connection has been closed

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-connector

Is it possible for mysql to execute a script even when the connection has been closed?
I am using mysql community server , through a .NET connector API. 
Was using c# to test out the API.

I have the following static class

```
using System;
using System.Data;

using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

public static class DataBase
{
    static string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;password=*******;";
    static MySqlConnection conn;

    public static bool Connect()
    {        
        conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);   
        try
        {            
            conn.Open();            
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler(Ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static int ExecuteScript(string scripttext) // returns the number of statements executed
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = scripttext;
        MySqlScript script;
        int count= 0;

        try
        {
            script = new MySqlScript(conn, cmd.CommandText);

            script.Error += new MySqlScriptErrorEventHandler(script_Error);
            script.ScriptCompleted += new EventHandler(script_ScriptCompleted);
            script.StatementExecuted += new MySqlStatementExecutedEventHandler(script_StatementExecuted);
            count = script.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            count = -1;
            ErrorHandler(Ex);            
        }
        return count;
    }

    # region EventHandlers
    static void script_StatementExecuted(object sender, MySqlScriptEventArgs args)
    {
        string Message = "script_StatementExecuted";
    }

    static void script_ScriptCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string Message = "script_ScriptCompleted!";
    }

    static void script_Error(Object sender, MySqlScriptErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        string Message = "script_Error: " + args.Exception.ToString();
    }
    # endregion
    public static bool Disconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            ErrorHandler(Ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    public static void ErrorHandler(Exception Ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Source);
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(Ex.ToString());
    }

}
```

and I am using the following code to test out this class

```
using System;
using System.Data;
namespace Sample
{
    public class Sample
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            if (DataBase.Connect() == true)
                Console.WriteLine("Connected");

            if (DataBase.Disconnect() == true)
                Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");

            int count = DataBase.ExecuteScript("drop database sample");
            if (count != -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Sample Script Executed");
                Console.WriteLine(count);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();

        }


    }
}
```

I noticed that even though I have closed my MySql connection using Disconnect() - which i have defined, mysql continues to execute the command i give next and no error is generated.

I feel  like I am doing something wrong, as an error should be generated when i try to execute a script on a closed connection.

Is it a problem in my code/logic or some flaw in mysql connector?

I did check through the mysql workbench whether the command was executed properly and it was.

Comment: `novice` you may also want to refactor the code and wrap you connection code around a `using (){}` block as well as adding some conditional check to see if the connection is still open or not..

Comment: I was going to do exactly that. This was just a sample code to check if the connector API was working good. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a decompile of MySqlScript.Execute code....

```
public unsafe int Execute()
{

    ......

    flag = 0;
    if (this.connection != null)
    {
        goto Label_0015;
    }
    throw new InvalidOperationException(Resources.ConnectionNotSet);
Label_0015:
    if (this.query == null)
    {
        goto Label_002A;
    }
    if (this.query.Length != null)
    {
        goto Label_002C;
    }
Label_002A:
    return 0;
Label_002C:
    if (this.connection.State == 1)
    {
        goto Label_0047;
    }
    flag = 1;
    this.connection.Open();
    ....
```

As you can see, when you build the MySqlScript the connection passed is saved in an internal variable and before executing the script, if the internal connection variable is closed, the code opens it. Not checked but I suppose that it also closes the connection before exiting (notice that flag=1 before opening)

A part from this I suggest to change your code to avoid keeping a global MySqlConnection object. You gain nothing and risk to incur in very difficult bugs to track.

```
static string connStr = "server=localhost;user=root;port=3306;password=*******;";

public static MySqlConnection Connect()
{        
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);   
    conn.Open();            
    return conn;
}
```

This approach allows to write code that use the Using Statement

```
public static int ExecuteScript(string scripttext) // returns the number of statements executed
{
    using(MySqlConnection conn = Database.Connect())
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = scripttext;
        ....
    }
}
```

The Using statement will close and dispose the connection and the command freeing valuable resources and also in case of exception you will be sure to have the connection closed and disposed

Comment: So Execute opens the connection if it is closed? What would such a functionality serve.. I guess ill just check if the connection is open before executing the script. At least not doing anything wrong.

Comment: It is the same functionality adopted in the code of the DataAdapter. Here the docs on MSDN about [SqlDataAdapter.Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d(v=vs.110).aspx) See the Remarks section

Comment: wrt to the second part of your answer. If i take the suggested approach, the function ExecuteScript connects to the database everytime it is called. I want to avoid just that and keep a global mysql connection active, since it is a large project and requires per second reading and writing into the DB. I want to avoid this overhead. Any way to do this efficiently without keeping a global mysqlconnection object?

Comment: On the contrary, keeping a global connection object could be a very dangerous action for intensive database applications. Please read about [connection pooling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html).

Comment: yes, i dont want to keep a global connection object, because of the reasons you listed, but is there a faster way to do this? Save some processing time

Comment: Have you measured the difference in opening the connection between a global connection object and simply creating a new one and opening it with the SAME connection string? Don't trust me, do your benchmarks and you will find a negligible difference if any.